# How to find all the comments I posted on this site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

I commented on a question on Stack Overflow that I can no longer locate. I'm wondering: is there a way for me to link to all the questions on which I've commented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your comments in your profile under Activity tab.

Comment: Isn't that for a limited period though?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, maybe it's different on SO, but I just checked my profile on my oldest account, Mi Yodeya, and my activity goes all the way back to my Supporter badge the day I created the account in 2011.  My oldest comment is not long after that and is plausibly actually my oldest (a reply to a comment on my first question).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hmm - now I look at comments, and the oldest one I have is [February 12, 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535644/find-email-addresses-in-large-data-stream/539461#comment351988_539461). Maybe it's changed since I left that comment.

Answer (score 4):

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/291877/comments?pagesize=50

Answer (score 3):

There is a [data explorer query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/504/my-comments) to do this. The data will be slightly out-of-date though.