# Seeing all comments you made?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find all the comments I posted on this site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64109/how-to-find-all-the-comments-i-posted-on-this-site)

Is there a way to see all comments I have made on this site? There was a post on ways to get automatic notifications when question tagged X is posted, I'm trying to find the post, but only concrete thing I remember was that I left a comment on it

Answer (score 1):

You can look through **[comments you've made before the last data dump on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/484/retrieve-your-comments)**.

If it's recent, you can look in your `Activity` tab.

Comment: It is recent, and it is in his activity tag. In fact, [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53077/is-it-possible-to-be-notified-of-new-questions-with-particular-tags).

Comment: @mmyers - Good eyes.